# File is not getting deleted in Android Java?

Tags: java, android, delete-file, native-android

File is not getting deleted in Android, I have checked all premissions, and I tried all the solutions available in the internet but nothing helps. Your help will be highly assist me. Thanks in advance.

I used the below permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And this is the code I used

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String path = dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/Recordings/Call/" + filename;
File fdelete = new File(path);
    if (fdelete.exists()) {
      if (fdelete.delete()) {
        System.out.println("file Deleted :" + path);
      } else {                                              
        System.out.println("file not Deleted :" + path);
      }
 }
```

And the err log is

```
W/soft.my_app_name: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method void libcore.io.Linux.remove(java.lang.String)
```

[image]

Error log is

[image]

Comment: I can't see any error. I see only a warning

Comment: You really should use [`Files.delete(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete(java.nio.file.Path)) or [`Files.deleteIfExists(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#deleteIfExists(java.nio.file.Path)) ...

Comment: which Android API level are you testing on ?

Comment: I tested all these api versions 30,31,32